# Passing the value of checkbox to child component in Vue

Tags: vue.js, checkbox

I'm developing a Vue webpage for displaying GitLab pipelines. I have a main Vue component (i.e. "Monitor.vue") and X child components that display the pipelines schedules for each of the X projects on my GitLab instance (called "Schedules.vue").

In "Monitor" I'd like to have a checkbox that would **make the schedules' container disappear for the projects where no pipeline was scheduled yet**. This is what I wrote for doing so:

Monitor.vue:

```
<template> 
  <input type="checkbox" value="false" v-model="checked">
  Show only projects that have scheduled pipelines
  <div v-if="checked">Checkbox checked!</div>

  <div class="row">
    <div v-for="project in projects" :key="project.id">
      <Schedules :checkBoxChecked="checked"></Schedules>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Schedules from "./Schedules.vue";

  export default {
    components: {
      Schedules
    },
    data() {
      return {
        checked: false
      };
    }
  };
<script>
```

Schedules.vue:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="checkBoxChecked">
    No scheduled pipelines yet.
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <!-- Display pipelines here -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "Schedules",
    props: "checkBoxChecked"
  };
</script>
```

Now, the value of `checked` indeed changes in Monitor when I check the box but when I try to pass it to the child components, the value of checkBoxChecked in undefined in the web console.

What did I forget here?

Comment: it's `undefined` in bothes cases or just after you click on the checkbox

Comment: @mooga In both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `props` property isn't a string, it's an array or an object

```
export default {
    name: "Schedules",
    props: {
        checkBoxChecked: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Ha, so far I only had to handle properties that were strings. TIL, thank you Stephen!

Answer (score 0):

`props` is an object
 in Schedules.vue:

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: "Schedules",
    props: {
       "checkBoxChecked": Boolean
    }
  };
</script>
```